# How to successfully Install Azure CLI

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, installation, azure-cli

I'm having problem installing Azure CLI. I've tried three methods but all failed.

The first two are from [Install Azure CLI on Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?tabs=azure-powershell), I've tried

- install the Azure CLI using PowerShell, and
- Download and install the latest release of the Azure CLI .msi file myself.
- I've tried remove it and reinstalled using the .msi file as well.

But for all cases, if I type `az`, I'll get

`az : The term 'az' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`

Then I tried [Install the Azure CLI on Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-linux?pivots=apt) as last resort, but it failed too:

```sh
+ echo 'deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli/ bullseye main'
+ apt-get update
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease                                                                
Hit:3 http://ftp.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports InRelease                                                      
Hit:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease                                                        
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/suntong001/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                               
Get:6 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli bullseye InRelease [10.4 kB]
Err:6 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli bullseye InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF
Reading package lists... Done
W: http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/bullseye-security/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg are ignored as the file is not readable by user '_apt' executing apt-key.
W: http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg are ignored as the file is not readable by user '_apt' executing apt-key.
W: http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye-backports/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg are ignored as the file is not readable by user '_apt' executing apt-key.
W: http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye-updates/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg are ignored as the file is not readable by user '_apt' executing apt-key.
W: http://ppa.launchpad.net/suntong001/ppa/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg are ignored as the file is not readable by user '_apt' executing apt-key.
W: https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli/dists/bullseye/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg are ignored as the file is not readable by user '_apt' executing apt-key.
W: GPG error: https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli bullseye InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF
E: The repository 'https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli bullseye InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: On windows: Did you restart your machine after installing?

Comment: Restarting the Windows machine does have some magic tricks that are beyond my comprehension but it did work. Thanks @MarkusMeyer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows, you can find the Azure CLI *az.cmd* here:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin`

And this path can be found in the Environment variable `Path`:
[image]

PowerShell:
`$Env:Path`

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin;

If you install Azure CLI with a msi file, it will install the application and add the location to the `Path` variable.

If there's an open PowerShell, the `Path` is not refreshed automatically in the background.
You have to close PowerShell and open a new session. Usually, the updated `Path` is loaded.
This behavior also applies to a lot more applications.

So, it might make sense (or if you want to be on the safe side) to restart your machine.

BTW: It's also possible to [refresh Environment Variables in Windows 11 (Without Reboot)](https://thecategorizer.com/windows/how-to-refresh-environment-variables-in-windows/) with e.g. Chocolatey